# Iterate through array and push only one of each element to another array

Tags: arrays, angular, loops

I have array that i get from service, and in that array I have elements that are same (example: 1,2,2,3,1,1,3). I want to make another array that will contain only one of each elements from previous array (so new array should look like [1,2,3 etc). Can you point me to error in this function. Thanks

```
this.dataService.get().subscribe( response => {

        this.Data = response;
        response.forEach(res => {
            for (this.i = 0; this.i < this.headData.length; this.i++){
                res.head !== this.headData[this.i];
            }
            this.headData.push(res.head);
        }) }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-an-array-remove-duplicates

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/5050924

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Set`  to generate unique items in the array

```
var items = [1,2,2,3,1,1,3]
var uniqueItems = Array.from(new Set(items))
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33121880/6651984)

Or you can use [sortedUniq Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#sortedUniq) fucntions.

```
_.sortedUniq([1, 1, 2]);
// this is the result  => [1, 2]
```